This localhost page can’t be found - No webpage was found for the web address.- ASP.NET Core
I have recently created a new aspsettings.json by deleting aspsettings..json to correct the file name and resolve an error, I have two controllers - Home and Employees.
Right now, once I run the Index page, I get this message:

This localhost page can't be found - No webpage was found for the web address.

Here's the code for the Index method of my HomeController:
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

     public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
     {
         _logger = logger;
     }

     public IActionResult Index()
     {
         return View("Index");
     }

     public IActionResult Privacy()
     {
         return View();
     }
}

The appsettings.json config is this:
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": ";Database={Employees};User Id={Ammadlogin};Password={ammadpass1}Trust Server Certificate=True;"
    },
    "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Here's the Program.cs:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Employeeproject
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            var app = builder.Build();
            app.Run();

            // Add services to the container.
            var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}

I have tried to see the controller, the Index functionality is there. The HomeController and page index is mentioned on the Program.cs as well. So the route is correct.

your error message is not related to appsettings.json. Is web server even running? Also, please read [ask] and clean numerous typos in your question. Makes it difficult to help you
